# WCF Service: Isn't too expensive to use WCF service for very simple interface implementation

Tags: web-services, wcf

I know, WCF Service is better then ASP.NET Web Service due to (a lot of reasons). But is it reasonable to use WCF service if everything you need is to have 3 simple methods, each of them with 2-3 parameters?

For me it seems like firing on birds with cannon.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: WCF is great and absolutely well suited for a situation like this! Just begin to use it, enjoy it, get to love it - just do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That a framework has features you don't need isn't a great reason not to use it. WCF will work great for a simple service of just a couple methods, and you'll have the flexibility of protocol bindings, extensibility, security, etc. there if you ever need it. That said, the 3.0 version of WCF did require a lot of intellectual overhead to get started; the team is working to reduce this and make it as easy as asmx to get started. If you can, use 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few opinions out there on this.  The most common theme that I come across is to your point, simple job/simple service.  That being said I think it is pretty quick and easy to throw together a WCF service and have been converting any of our legacy ASMX services to WCF as they need updating, even the smaller ones.